# Логическая формулировка

Tags: грамотная-речь

Прошу помочь разрешить возникший спор.
Небольшое введение: *Фотография красивого заката* и комментарий под ней:

"Bот такой вот закатный релакс на прогулке с собакой. Омрачается он тем, что за собаками тут нужно убирать в обязательном порядке. Но не для меня – предпочитаю домой приходить в чистой обуви. Как вы к этому относитесь, кстати? Убираете за собаками?"

Есть ли логическиe ошибки, с точки зрения языка, в данной формулировке?

Comment: Скажите, зачем вы пишете не по-русски?

Comment: Будьте добры, используйте кириллические символы, создавая сообщения. http://i.voenmeh.ru/kafi5/Kam.loc/inform/UTF-8.htm

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой Что там с символами - это, конечно, интересно. Но зачем было перепечатывать-то?

Comment: @oleedd: а зачем оставлять такое?

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой А внешне никаких отличий нет. Символы идентичны.

Comment: Я просто не понимаю, сложно объяснить, что ли, зачем он так делает.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой Вопрос ещё в том, как делает? Переключать раскладку для идентичных английских символов очень затруднительно. Может, через какую-то программу. Знаю сайт, который так защищает свой текст. Слова из него (часто очень специфические) из-за этого не гуглятся. Тоже непонятно зачем.

Comment: Перед первым предложением логичным было бы введение, какие бывают виды релакса в зависимости от времени суток и пояснение, что такое "омрачение релакса".

Comment: @Alex_ander А зачем? Релакс - это отдых, просто английская версия. Омрачение - что-то портит (омрачает) отдых. И так всё ясно.

Comment: В английском relax - исключительно **глагол**, так что здесь - жаргонизм узкой группы "переводчиков". В тексте очень длинная для восприятия логика, поэтому надо хотя бы расшифровать эту "расслабуху". Тогда можно будет раскусить оставшуюся логику. Причина, "омрачающая релакс", - порядок (в месте релакса) убирать за собаками. С одной стороны, для любителей халявы (это не я, а другие) это плохо тем, что над собственной собакой надо потрудиться, зато если другие соблюдают порядок, сам не вляпаешься (я готов, так что мой релакс этим не омрачить).

Comment: @Alex_ander Никак не исключительно: https://i.imgur.com/Nojj7H6.png

Comment: В серьёзных словарях (напр. Мюллер или Апресян, где словарная статья занимает почти страницу) это только глагол. Существительное же - relax_ation_. А здесь, вероятно, спортивный жаргонизм.

Comment: Современные словари даже как американизм не фиксируют relax в значении существительного: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/relax

Comment: @Alex_ander По последней ссылке словарь очень хороший и полезный, но уже не раз убеждаюсь, что там не все значения. || Расшифровывать что-то в подобных текстах (комментариях) — глупость. Это не учебник или книга, где можно сделать приметку/сноску. Тогда лучше не использовать само слово и заменить на "отдых". Да и прогулку с собакой релаксацией (расслаблением) не назовёшь: по крайней мере, нужно всегда быть начеку и следить за собакой. "Какие бывают виды релакса в зависимости от времени суток" — эта идея меня вообще в тупик поставила. Как будто существует такая классификация...

Comment: Я тоже остановился на этом слове раньше ("релакс"), мне оно не понравилось. Поддерживаю Александра, что это исключительно глагол в английском.

Comment: @Alex_ander Зная уже русское слово "релаксация", значение "релакса" проблемой не будет.

Answer (score 1):

Мне здесь всё кажется нелогичным (в прямом и переносном смысле).

***Фотография красивого заката и комментарий под ней: Такой вот закатный релакс на прогулке с собакой.***

Это начало текста, и читатель справедливо ожидает, что автор поделится своими впечатлениями о красивом закате, а он о чем рассказывает?!

***Омрачается он (релакс?) тем, что за собаками тут нужно убирать в обязательном порядке.***

Но автор **неожиданно переходит к негативу** —  ситуация "омрачается", причем не сказано ДЛЯ КОГО? Кажется, что для него самого, то есть убирать **за собакой ЕМУ не хочется**.

***Но не для меня – предпочитаю домой приходить в чистой обуви.***  Нет, ему нравятся такие порядки, они лишний повод **для положительных эмоций** по поводу чистой обуви, но тогда зачем использовать слово "омрачает"? Про людей, не убирающих за собакой, которых правила выгула могут расстроить, не сказано ни слова.

Нет, я бы так не стала подписывать фотографию с красивым закатом.

**Вариант редактирования (с исправлением логической ошибки):**

Bот такой закатный релакс на прогулке с собакой. **РАДУЕТ** то, что за собаками тут нужно убирать в обязательном порядке. **Некоторых это огорчает**, но только не  меня – предпочитаю домой приходить в чистой обуви. Как вы к этому относитесь, кстати? Убираете за собаками?

Comment: Такое занятие никак не может радовать. Из-за этого момента у вас ещё нелогичнее получилось. Можно решить так: ***Для большинства** он омрачается тем*.

Comment: То, что площадка будет чистой, не может не радовать. Радует здесь не само занятие,  как вы считаете,  а ПРАВИЛА.

Comment: Да, это было бы логичным, если бы у рассказчика не было собаки. А так — радовать не может, так как есть весомый негативный аспект, но может не огорчать. Оно нивелируется по смыслу.

Comment: О весомом негативном аспекте вам лучше поговорить с автором вопроса.

Comment: Так может сказать только заядлый оптимист и трудяга.

Comment: Вот и познакомитесь заодно,  проверите свои знания в области психологии.

Comment: Он уже забросил этот сайт. Да и пишется, что незарегистрированный.

Comment: Зато сколько просмотров!  Заходят любители логических формулировок?  Или еще что-то сюда привлекает посетителей?

Comment: Логика всех привлекает. Она правит этим миром)

Comment: Это вряд ли. Скорее всего,  в соцсетях на вопрос дали ссылку.

Answer (score 0):

Смысл действительно несколько затемнён, его можно понять двояко. Может быть, **логическая ошибка видится тем читателям комментария, которые отнесли "Но не для меня" к обязательному порядку убирать за собаками.** Складывается впечатление, что автор комментария против этого порядка. Тогда нелогично его замечание о чистой обуви.

Но мне видится, что **"не для меня" относится к "омрачению"**. Он утверждает, что красота пейзажа не омрачается тем, что приходится заниматься таким низменным - убирать за собакой, ведь если все этого не будут делать в обязательном порядке,   есть вероятность испачкать обувь. Здесь всё логично.

Comment: "*которые отнесли "Но не для меня" к обязательному порядку убирать за собаками*" — тогда было бы "*Но не мне (нужно убирать)*" или "*Но это не для меня*". А так: *омрачается, но не для меня*.

Comment: Вот именно, здесь логика не нарушена. Вопрос ведь о наличии логической ошибки.